# javascript function with two elements and web audio api

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I want to make a function to control two parameters in web audio api, those parameters change according to an input element on html5. I dont know how to make it work as needed.

This is the code for the input slider:

```
<div>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" oninput="BrownVol(this);" />BrownVol</input>
</div>
```

and the function:

```
BrownVol = function(element) {
  var fraction = parseInt(element.value) / parseInt(element.max);
  this.gain_3.gain.value = fraction * fraction;
};
```

I want to add another parameter in the input, like:

```
<div>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" oninput="BrownVol(this, gain_3);" />BrownVol</input>
</div>
```

and replace the second parameter in the function

```
BrownVol = function(element, type) {
  var fraction = parseInt(element.value) / parseInt(element.max);
  this.type.gain.value = fraction * fraction;
};
```

And even better if I could define the parameter like "gain_3.gain" or so...

I tried this, but doesn't work.

I dont know how to do it, could somebody help me, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your second function, you pass in `type`

```
BrownVol = function(element, type) {
```

But you try to call it like this

```
this.type.gain.value = fraction * fraction;
```

`type` is not recognized as a property of this. If it is a property of this and the name itself is not variable, you shouldn't pass it in as a parameter. If it is sometimes `gain_3` and sometimes `gain_4`, you should have it as a value, not a key, such as `gain['value'] = 3`, then passing in `gain` will get you the desired value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
Type is a variable, I have several with the same name format: gain_1 to gain_4
In Web Audio Api I have defined gainNodes with the name gain_x, I want to modify the gain value of that gainNode with a slider

Comment: Then definitely use a key value pair. rather than trying to use the variable name itself as the value, pass it a consistent representation who's value changes. Use a multidimensional array if needed.